# jquery div fadeout on child form event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in jquery/javascript and couldn't google for any solution.

I have number of divs generated automatically from cycle. Each of them contains form as a child element.  So on form submit I'd like the corresponding parent div to fadeout.

I am using Ajax for form submission. Basically, now I have an event handler 'submit' binded to all child forms within divs. Here what it looks like

```
        $('#divCreatedActivities').children('div').children('form').submit(function() {
            var options = { 
                    target:        $('#divCreatedActivities').children('div'), 
                    dataType:      'xml',
                    success:       submittedActivity
            };
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
            return false; 
        });

        function submittedActivity() {
            alert('ahoy!');     
        }
```

How can I do that with JQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the source for the divs in question? We could give you the necessary selectors then...

Comment: I updated the question with piece of source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

That's the way to do it. But I have a question, how can you see it fading when it's submitting?? Isn't it reloading or something? Are you using ajax?

---

based from your edited post,

```
$('#divCreatedActivities form').submit(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var options = { 
         target:        $('#divCreatedActivities').children('div'), 
         dataType:      'xml',
         success:       function() {
                     $this.parent().fadeOut();
                     alert('ahoy!');    
         }
    };
    $this.ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
});

/* remove this
function submittedActivity() {
    alert('ahoy!');     
} */
```

<sub>Welcome to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)</sub>
<sub>Don't forget to accept an answer</sub>

Comment: yes, I am using Ajax. I updated a question with piece of code

Comment: Thank you! $this.parent().fadeOut(); throws an error on $this. I made it $(this), alert is firing, but still no fadeOut. Maybe it has something to do with live() function, since divs are generated on the fly? edit: missed the line var $this = $(this). Works as a charm with this! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler to fade out the div containing the form:

```
$('#theFormId').submit(function() {
    $('#theDiv').fadeOut();
});
```

**However**, unless you delay the form submission or use ajax instead of normal form submission, the animation may never happen — because a normal form submission tears down the page and replaces it with the result of the submission to the server. So for instance, if you want the fadeout to take 500ms, you could do this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/itawu4)):

```
// #theFormId can be any selector that selects the form(s) you want
// handled in this way; it's just an example
$('#theFormId').submit(function() {
    // `this` is set to the form's raw DOM element, remember it for use
    // in the closure below.
    var form = this;

    // Get a jQuery wrapper for the form element, use it to find the
    // first containing div. Start a fadeout on that div, and use the
    // fadeout callback to trigger the actual form submission.
    $(this).parents('div:first').fadeOut(500, function() {
        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    });

    // Disable *this* form submission in favor of the above
    return false;
});
```

Of course, that delays the form submission by half a second, which not all users may like... Also, if you're relying on knowing which submit button the user pressed, the above loses that (because we're not submitting the form using the button anymore, we're cancelling that one and then submitting it later with code).

In the above I'm using [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) with the selector "div:first" to find the first ancestor element that's a div; you can modify that selector as appropriate, or if the div is the *immediate* parent of the form, you can just use [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) instead.

Comment: I think you can put the submitting part in callback of fadeOut.

Comment: `return false;` on the `form` was what I had in mind. But it did not work for me. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqxEw/)

Comment: thank you, but I think sticking to '#id' is not an option in this case, since I don't know in advance on which div event will fire. Or maybe I just dont get it :)

Comment: @Paulus: I've updated the answer to explain a bit more and to demonstrate/discuss using `parents` or `parent` to find the relevant div.

Comment: @Reigel seems this code has a slight issue, I unbind `submit` event to get it work, see http://jsfiddle.net/dqxEw/1/ If we don't do so, I think this event handler will be invoked every 0.5 seconds. Another way to work around is to check if parent has been faded or not, if it has, then `return true;`

Comment: @Paulus: Added a live example

Comment: @T.J. I totally forgot that, stuck in jQuery world. :)

Comment: @livibetter: *"I think you can put the submitting part in callback of fadeOut."* Good idea, done. And you're right about the submit handler getting triggered again when using the jQuery `submit` (I ran into it as well); that's a jQuery thing. Your way of solving it works, as does mine above (using the DOM element's `submit` rather than jQuery's; the DOM element's `submit` does not call submit handlers, by design). See the working live example.

Comment: @livibetter: Just different ways of solving the same problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my-form-id').submit(function(){ $(this).parent().fadeOut(600); });
```

Comment: there's no specific #my-form-id, since I don't know in advance how many forms will be generated. Number of forms depends on previous selection, that user has made.